# Tengo un problema con re definir columnas y filas en una matriz solo lo hace una vez y cuando vuelvo a usarlo lo deja igual

Tags: java, funciones, matrices

```
public static void main (String args[])
{  int f = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuantas filas"));
   int c = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuantascolumnas"));
   int [][]mat = new int[f][c];int cont = 0;
    while(cont < 2)
    {   int [][]columR = redef_colum(mat);
        mat = columR;
       /* int [][]filaR = redef_fila(mat);
        mat = filaR;*/
        cont++;
    }
    String result = "";
    for(int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++)
    {   for(int y = 0; y< mat[x].length; y++)
        {  result += mat[x][y] + " "; } result += "\n";};
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,result);    } 

public static int[][] redef_colum(int m[][])
{  
    int[][] redef_colum = new int [m.length][m.length + 1];        
    for(int f = 0; f < redef_colum.length; f++)
    {   for(int c = 0; c < redef_colum[f].length; c++)
        {  if(c < redef_colum.length)       
           { redef_colum[f][c] = m[f][c];}
           else
           {redef_colum[f][c] = 0;}                
        }            
    }  
    return redef_colum;
}
public static int[][] redef_fila(int m[][])
{  
    int[][] redef_fila = new int [m.length +1][m.length];       
    for(int f = 0; f < redef_fila.length; f++)
    { 
        if(f < redef_fila[f].length) 
        { for(int c = 0; c < redef_fila[f].length; c++)
            { redef_fila[f][c] = m[f][c];}
        } 
        else{
            for(int c = 0; c < redef_fila[f].length; c++)
            { redef_fila[f][c] = 0; }
        }       
   } 
   return redef_fila;
}
```

Comment: tambien publica el **Main** o funcion principal, y especifica un poco mas tu problema es muy amplio.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Revisando el código que colocas encuentro que el primer error esta en la linea

```
int[][] redef_colum = new int[m.length][m.length + 1];
```

Esto a que estas definiendo la matriz `redef_colum` con solo el número de filas; esta línea debería ser

```
int[][] redef_colum = new int[m.length][m[0].length + 1];
```

2 - Esta parte del ciclo de copiado no es necesaria

```
if (c < redef_colum.length) {
   redef_colum[f][c] = m[f][c];
} else {
   redef_colum[f][c] = 0;
}
```

debido a que `a)` cuando defines una matriz de enteros está por default se llena con el valor cero `0` y `b)` Siempre vas a copiar a una matriz mayor por lo cual solo debes recorrer la matriz original (matriz `m`) y pasarla a la matriz destino (matriz `redef_colum`).

```
for (int f = 0; f < m.length; f++) {
     for (int c = 0; c < m[f].length; c++) {
          redef_colum[f][c] = m[f][c];
     }
 }
```

Ahora, esto es valido si y solo si, la matriz origen tiene datos, por que si esta vacia (toda la matriz en cero) no es requerido hacer este copiado.

3 - Debes hacer los mismos cambios en el método `public static int[][] redef_fila(int m[][])`

4 - Para recorrer la matriz y almacenar sus valores en una sola variable String, es preferible que uses un  `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < mat[x].length; y++) {
         result.append(mat[x][y]);
         result.append(" ");
    }
    result.append("\n") ;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result.toString());
```